# How to reload extension from ViewController in CallKit framework swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit

Currently I am trying with `callDirManager.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "com.companyname.appname", completionHandler: nil)` this method but its not working for me. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
import CallKit

 CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: 
   "your Identifier") { (error) in 

        //some code
   }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to start by implementing the completionHandler callback and examine the optional error object that it passes.

Comment: We have implemented completion handler but not getting any kind of error.